# Change the JSON serialization settings of a single ASP.NET Core controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having two controller controllers: `ControllerA` and `ControllerB`. The base class of each controller is `Controller`.

The `ControllerA` needs to return JSON in the default format (camelCase). The `ControllerB` needs to return data in a different JSON format: snake_case.

How can I implement this in ASP.NET Core 3.x and 2.1?

I've tried the `startup` with:

```
services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
        {
            NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
        };
    })
    .AddControllersAsServices();
```

But this will change the serialization for **all** controllers, not just for `ControllerB`. How can I configure or annotate this feature for 1 controller?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

#### ASP.NET Core 3.0+

You can achieve this with a combination of an [Action Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1#action-filters) and an [Output Formatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.formatters.outputformatter?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Things look a little different for 3.0+, where the default JSON-formatters for 3.0+ are based on `System.Text.Json`. At the time of writing, these [don't have built-in support for a snake-case naming strategy](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/782).

However, if you're using Json.NET with 3.0+ (details in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#jsonnet-support)), the `SnakeCaseAttribute` from above is still viable, with a couple of changes:

1. `JsonOutputFormatter` is now `NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter`.
2. The `NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter` constructor requires an argument of `MvcOptions`.

Here's the code:

```
public class SnakeCaseAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext ctx)
    {
        if (ctx.Result is ObjectResult objectResult)
        {
            objectResult.Formatters.Add(new NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter(
                new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
                    {
                        NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
                    }
                },
                ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ArrayPool<char>>(),
                ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcOptions>>().Value));
        }
    }
}
```

### ASP.NET Core 2.x

You can achieve this with a combination of an [Action Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#action-filters) and an [Output Formatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.formatters.outputformatter?view=aspnetcore-2.1). Here's an example of what the Action Filter might look like:

```
public class SnakeCaseAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext ctx)
    {
        if (ctx.Result is ObjectResult objectResult)
        {
            objectResult.Formatters.Add(new JsonOutputFormatter(
                new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
                    {
                        NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
                    }
                },
                ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ArrayPool<char>>()));
        }
    }
}
```

Using `OnActionExecuted`, the code runs after the corresponding action and first checks to see if the result is an `ObjectResult` (which also applies to `OkObjectResult` thanks to inheritance). If it is an `ObjectResult`, the filter simply adds a customised version of a [`JsonOutputFormatter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.formatters.jsonoutputformatter?view=aspnetcore-2.1) that will serialise the properties using `SnakeCaseNamingStrategy`. The second parameter in the `JsonOutputFormatter` constructor is retrieved from the DI container.

In order to use this filter, just apply it to the relevant controller:

```
[SnakeCase]
public class ControllerB : Controller { }
```

---

Note: You might want to create the `JsonOutputFormatter`/`NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter` ahead of time somewhere, for example - I've not gone that far in the example as that's secondary to the question at hand.

Answer (score 5):

No need for action filters etc. Just override `Json()` in your controller and that's it.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public override JsonResult Json(object data)
    {
        return base.Json(data, new JsonSerializerSettings {
            // set whataever default options you want
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I had to prevent camelCase property naming policy, at action level only, by sticking to `System.Text.Json`.

So, I combined @Kirk's answer and another one from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59701123/8075004) :

```
public class NoPropertyNamingPolicyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private static readonly SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter SSystemTextJsonOutputFormatter = new SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter(new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        // do not apply any policy,
        // leave the property names as they are defined in the TestResponse class:
        PropertyNamingPolicy = null,

        // to apply camelCase policy:
        //PropertyNamingPolicy = System.Text.Json.JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
    });

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Result is ObjectResult objectResult)
        {
            objectResult.Formatters.Add(SSystemTextJsonOutputFormatter);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[HttpGet("test")]
[NoPropertyNamingPolicy]
public TestResponse TestAction()
{
    return new TestResponse();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ended up creating this method that I use on my end points:

```
{           
    // needed to get the same date and property formatting 
    // as the Search Service:
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
        {
            NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
        },
        DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ"
    };

    return Json(result, settings);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### ASP.NET Core 6.0+

Follows the majority of the details from 3.0+ section. Although now, `NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter(JsonSerializerSettings, ArrayPool<Char>, MvcOptions)` is obsolete [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.formatters.newtonsoftjsonoutputformatter.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-8.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-formatters-newtonsoftjsonoutputformatter-ctor(newtonsoft-json-jsonserializersettings-system-buffers-arraypool((system-char))-microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-mvcoptions)).

The most updated version adds a new parameter on the end as `MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions`. This is consistent with Microsoft working with Newtonsoft.  I would assume from Microsoft comment

> The Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings. Should be either the application-wide settings (SerializerSettings) or an instance CreateSerializerSettings() initially returned.

...that you need to configure your service controllers to NewtonSoftJson if you're using it. Otherwise adding a `null` or `new MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions()` value could be comparable.

```
servicesCollection.AddControllers()
     .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings
     .NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore);
```

I find that overriding the `ActionFilterAttribute.OnResultExecutionAsync` call is a cleaner route.  By injecting in-between the call, you grab it before the result is finalized. Then call it's base to continue the actions it intended to trigger.

```
await base.OnResultExecutionAsync(ctx, next);
```

While this is a preference, you can override `OnResultExecuting()` to receive similar results, and not needing to call it's base function.

Here's the code:

```
public class SnakeCaseAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public async override Task OnResultExecutionAsync(ResultExecutingContext ctx, ResultExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if (ctx.Result is ObjectResult objectResult)
        {
            objectResult.Formatters.Add(new NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter(
                new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
                    {
                        NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
                    }
                },
                ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ArrayPool<char>>(),
                ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcOptions>>().Value,
                new MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions()));
        }
        await base.OnResultExecutionAsync(ctx, next);
    }
}
```