# How do you remove nulls from api controllers in asp.net core?

Tags: json, asp.net-core

This seems like a duplicate but my searches weren't returning any applicable results.

Is there a way to tell a specific api controller in asp.net core to remove any null entries in the object being returned as json?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507889/how-to-ignore-a-property-in-class-if-null-using-json-net

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52605946/change-the-json-serialization-settings-of-a-single-asp-net-core-controller/52623772#52623772) should give you all the information you need to achieve this.