# Change System.Text.Json Serialization Options of a single ASP.NET Core API controller or single Action in ASP.NET Core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, deserialization, system.text.json

I'm having two controller controllers: ControllerA and ControllerB. The base class of each controller is ControllerBase.

The ControllerA needs to deserialize JSON in the default option

```
JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = false;
```

The ControllerB needs to deserialize JSON with option

```
JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
```

I know how to set this option global in Startup.cs

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions( options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true);
```

But how to set specific deserialize options to Controller or Action? (ASP.NET Core 3 API)

Comment: You can try to achieve it with an ActionFilter, and [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52605946/change-the-json-serialization-settings-of-a-single-asp-net-core-controller) discussed a similar requirement, you can refer to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the JSON serialization settings of a single ASP.NET Core controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52605946/change-the-json-serialization-settings-of-a-single-asp-net-core-controller)

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by Fei Han, the straight-forward answer is to use on ControllerB the attribute `NullValuesJsonOutput` :

```
public class NullValuesJsonOutputAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private static readonly SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter Formatter = new SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter(new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        IgnoreNullValues = true
    });

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Result is ObjectResult objectResult)
            objectResult.Formatters.Add(Formatter);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to post this answer on the question I've linked as a duplicate, as this question is likely to get closed.

Comment: @IanKemp There's already a good answer on the duplicate (also pointed by Fei Han), which I adapted for this question.