# return JSON as is (PascalCase) from one Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

in asp.net core 3 the returned json will get automatically transformed to camelCase, and I know how to turn this off globally but how do I turn this off for one single action ?
I know it was supposed to be something like

```
return Json(myObj, cfgHere);
```

but can't find this example anywhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller.json?view=aspnetcore-3.1) method is part of `Controller`, but isn't part of `ControllerBase`. If you're using `ControllerBase`, which is typical for controllers that don't use views, you can new up a `JsonResult` and return that:

```
return new JsonResult(myObj, cfgHere);
```

This is all the `Controller.Json` method really does, as can be seen in the [source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/release/3.1/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/Controller.cs#L315-L318):

> ```
> public virtual JsonResult Json(object data, object serializerSettings)
> {
>     return new JsonResult(data, serializerSettings);
> }
> ```

`serializerSettings` can be either [`JsonSerializerOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions) or [`JsonSerializerSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm) (if you're using Json.NET). Here's an example that assumes you're using the default, `System.Text.Json`-based formatters:

```
return new JsonResult(myObj, new JsonSerializerOptions());
```

By creating an instance of `JsonSerializerOptions` without setting any properties, the [`PropertyNamingPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.propertynamingpolicy?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_PropertyNamingPolicy) is left as the *default* policy, which leaves the property names as-is.

If you'd like to use a more declarative approach, which supports content-negotiation, see: [Change the JSON serialization settings of a single ASP.NET Core controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52605946/change-the-json-serialization-settings-of-a-single-asp-net-core-controller/52623772).