# C# Asp.Netcore31: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonInputFormatter' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have Asp.Netcore3.1 Web API App. Right when my startup calls 'app.UseEndpoints()' in the 'Configure()' method below exception is thrown.I have the specified assembly as a nuget package reference in my app so not sure why this is not loading. I also converted my entire App to use System.Text.Json now with no reference to Newtonsoft.

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException
  HResult=0x80131602
  Message=Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonInputFormatter' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json, Version=3.1.18.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonOutputFormatter' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json, Version=3.1.18.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_DefinedTypes()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.AssemblyPart.get_Types()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFeatureProvider.PopulateFeature(IEnumerable`1 parts, ControllerFeature feature)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateFeature[TFeature](TFeature feature)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetControllerTypes()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetDescriptors()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ActionDescriptorProviderContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.UpdateCollection()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.GetChangeToken()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointDataSourceBase.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Subscribe>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.ChangeTokenRegistration`1..ctor(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action`1 changeTokenConsumer, TState state)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.OnChange(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action changeTokenConsumer)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointDataSourceBase.Subscribe()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ControllerActionEndpointDataSource..ctor(IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actions, ActionEndpointFactory endpointFactory)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.GetOrCreateDataSource(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapControllers(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
   at Startup.<>c.<Configure>b__11_0(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints) in Startup.cs:line 312
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.EndpointRoutingApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseEndpoints(IApplicationBuilder builder, Action`1 configure)
   at .Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IOptionsMonitor`1 sharedSettings, IEmsServiceContext serviceContext, IAppConfigurationCache appConfigurationCache) in Startup.cs:line 310
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
```

Comment: One note. I did try deleting all controllers except the most basic controller in my app to make sure was not related to anything from controller specific code being loaded.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

The installation packages you use are only applicable to ASP.NET Core 2.2 and lower versions.

Besides, please check the [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#newtonsoftjson-jsonnet-support) document:

As part of the work to improve the ASP.NET Core shared framework, Newtonsoft.Json (Json.NET) has been removed from the ASP.NET Core shared framework. the default JSON serializer for ASP.NET Core is now [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-overview)

So, you could try to use the System.Text.Json Or using the Newtonsoft.Json in an ASP.NET Core.

More detail information, please check the following links:

[Newtonsoft.Json (Json.NET) support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#newtonsoftjson-jsonnet-support)

[Change the JSON serialization settings of a single ASP.NET Core controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52605946/change-the-json-serialization-settings-of-a-single-asp-net-core-controller)

Comment: Maybe I was not clear in my original post but I did already remove all references to Newtonsoft and convert all code to System.Text.Json. That is done. I have done full code search and verified newtsoft does not appear in any code. All classes using System.Text.Json.

Comment: I did do some more debugging and have identified that issue seems to come when I load a specific class that has reference to an internal 3rd party component (developed by other team within my company that is shared with other teams) that happens to have a reference to Newtonsoft. None of the classes here are exposed within my webapi and should just be internal use. Why would these cause an issue?