# ASP.NET Core 5 add action filter with parameter

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, action-filter

Trying to add an authentication filter to an ASP.NET Core 5 MVC action method and pass a parameter. However I'm unable to find a way to do this. This is the action filter code:

```
public class CheckUserPrivilege : IActionFilter
{
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private readonly ISession _session;
        public string PrivilegeCode { get; set; }

        public CheckUserPrivilledge(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            _session = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;
        }
}
```

The parameter we need to pass is `PrivilegeCode`. Ideally want something like `[CheckUserPrivilege("abc")]` but when we try like so, I presume it also asks for the IHttpContextAccessor` parameter in the constructor.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use `IHttpContextAccessor` to get parameter , You just need to use the following code :

```
public class CheckUserFilter : Attribute,IActionFilter
    {
        
        private readonly string PrivilegeCode;
        public CheckUserFilter(string _PrivilegeCode)
        {
            PrivilegeCode = _PrivilegeCode;
        }
        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            //........
        }

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            //If you want to do somthing about context,
           // you just need to use`context.HttpContext.....`

            
        }
    }
```

when you try `[CheckUserPrivilege("abc")]` ,you can get the value in filter

[image]

Comment: Thank you. seems to do the job

Comment: More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52605946/change-the-json-serialization-settings-of-a-single-asp-net-core-controller/52623772#52623772), which include Core2 Core3 and core6 pending