# Does Newtonsoft's JsonSerializerSettings compiles itself in memory?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, jit

Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52605946/change-the-json-serialization-settings-of-a-single-asp-net-core-controller) I created `[SnakeCase]` ActionFilterAttribute, so some of my controllers return `JSON`s in `snake_case`.

It works, however what I've found is that it **consumes lot of CPU**.

Original code:

```
public class SnakeCaseAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Result is ObjectResult objectResult)
        {
            objectResult.Formatters.Add(new NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter(
                new JsonSerializerSettings // this is the culprit
                {
                    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
                    {
                        NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy
                        {
                            OverrideSpecifiedNames = false
                        },
                    },
                },
                context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ArrayPool<char>>(),
                context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcOptions>>().Value));
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnActionExecuted(context);
        }
    }
}
```

It took me few days to find, that following code is about x10-x15 faster!

```
public class SnakeCaseAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private static JsonSerializerSettings jss = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
        {
            NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy
            {
                OverrideSpecifiedNames = false
            },
        },
    };

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Result is ObjectResult objectResult)
        {
            objectResult.Formatters.Add(new NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter(
                jss, // change is here!!!
                context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ArrayPool<char>>(),
                context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcOptions>>().Value));
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnActionExecuted(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't understand why it is so.

I did monitor my app with `dotnet-counters` and I've found that for the slow case (1st example) there was (apart from huge CPU usage) this weird value:

```
Time spent in JIT (ms / 1 sec)                                         1051.12
```

(this value was fluctuating, but always around 1000)

When I changed the code, it is around ~10ms/s (100x times less):

```
Time spent in JIT (ms / 1 sec)                                         7.162
```

I suspect that with first example, when `JsonSerializerSettings` is created every time, it somehow triggers lot of JIT compilation that was using lot of CPU.

I would like to understand this mechanism, and what is really going on inside Newtonsoft's code in that case.

Comment: You just instantiated 3 objects everytime, have you checked the performance of their constructors?

Comment: Yes, I did. It is around 10ns (nanoseconds), meaning 0.01ms. Please note that only difference is `JsonSerializerSettings` and 2 other object are identical in both variants.

Comment: See [Does Json.NET cache types' serialization information?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33558665/3744182) and [Performance Tips: Reuse Contract Resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/performance.htm#ReuseContractResolver).  Contract creation (which uses reflection) is slow so the contract resolver caches and reuses the contract.  If you construct a new resolver for each call, you lose that performance advantage.  By using a static resolver you get the performance back again.

Comment: Thx @dbc, I have my answer.